# How to add IF condition to a auto filter using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have list of company names in column A and i am going to place a auto filter to select a few companies and then work with that data - I am able to do this using the following code, however the problem arises if the particular company name is not in the list itself- but still i need to work with the rest of the steps

```
Sub Test() 
   Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A:H").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ' here i need a if condtion so that if the company is it not in the list then it should go to the line 20 and continue the macro else continue with the next line itself 
    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("JTKPV LLC", "Living Inc."), Operator:=xlFilterValues
 ' If filter is false (i.e) if the company name is not present then it should skip the following line of codes 
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste ' Till here and then continue the next line of code

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter 'this will release the existing filter
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Selection.AutoFilter ' this will place a new filter
    Range("A1").Select
   Selection.AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:=Array("US", "UK", "AUS"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
   Selection.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=">10.00", Operator:=xlAnd
 ' And few more codes 
End Sub
```

I Hope i have explained myself, pardon me for any mistakes as i am new to VBA coding

Comment: Look into OnError

Comment: Actually the filter line of code runs and does not gives any error, It just adds the AutoFilter and all the data are hidden except the first row, as the one in the "Criteria1" does not exists

Comment: Is your problem that you aren't sure how to do `Range("A:H").AutoFilter` to reset the filter after the first filter and before doing the second filter as `Range("A:H").AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:=Array("US", "UK", "AUS"), Operator:=xlFilterValues`?

Comment: As an aside, copying and pasting a range which spans hidden autofilter rows will copy the hidden rows too I believe... you'll need to use [`.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) or [`PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476.aspx)

Comment: @Wolfie - it should only copy the visible cells (At least, the macro recorder has a bug in it if it doesn't.  No, repeating the recorded macro still only copies the visible cells.)

Comment: @YowE3K hmm thought I had this problem in the past, must be imagining things because I just tested and you're correct.

Comment: @Wolfie - When I saw your comment I thought "oh yeah, that's right, that's why everyone always uses `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`", so I was surprised myself when I saw it wasn't needed.

Comment: @YowE3K I'm sure I'll remember why some time after this is resolved... Really the advice should be to use `myRange1.Value = myRange2.Value` anyway ;)

Comment: @YowE3K - I believe i have answered your question ( i have edited my original post)

Comment: @Wolfie - Ahh - using `myRange1.Value = myRange2.Value` **would** require `myRange2` to be set using `SpecialCells`.

Comment: @David - thanks - that has made the question much clearer

Comment: @YowE3K haha it seems I'm being a bit slow today heh, answering myself without realising it! David: thanks for the edit, made things clearer, let me know if my answer doesn't quite hit the nail on the head for you

Comment: @YowE3K - Thank you so much for the help -- It worked 
- Variatus & Wolfie - Appreciate your help so much, however I am so new to this i am unable to understand the code!!! :-( !! Still I thank you for the assistance and this will be a learning experience for me !!

Answer (score 0):

If the company is not in your list, it will have no effect on your autofilter, since it will be filtered out. However, here is a demo for how to identify which companies are in the list and a better method for filtering / copying them to another sheet:

```
Sub Test()
    ' Use With to avoid Select
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Dim companyArray As Variant
        companyArray = Array("JTKPV LLC", "Living Inc.")
        Dim inField1 As String
        Dim notInField1 As String
        Dim n As Long
        Dim found As Range
        ' Loop over companies, see if they are in
        For n = 0 To UBound(companyArray)
            Set found = .Columns("A").Find(what:=companyArray(n), lookat:=xlWhole)
            If found Is Nothing Then
                ' Create list of companies not in column A
                notInField1 = notInField1 & "," & companyArray(n)
            Else
                ' Create list of companies in column A
                inField1 = inField1 & "," & companyArray(n)
            End If
        Next n
        ' Filter based on column 1, for names in the inField1 list
        .Range("A:H").AutoFilter
        .Range("A:H").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Split(inField1, ","), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        ' Copy to another sheet
        Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("A:H")).Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1")

        ' Filter based on column
        .Range("A:H").AutoFilter
        ' ...
    End With
End Sub
```

---

If none of the companies in your array are present, then you could use

```
If inField1 = "" Then
   ' none of the companies were present
End If
```

to avoid the filtering and copy/paste operations.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably look to see which is the last row and, if that is row 1, not perform the steps that you are trying to avoid:

```
Sub Test() 
    Dim lastRow As Long
    With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:H")
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("JTKPV LLC", "Living Inc."), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 
        If lastRow > 1 Then
            .Range("A1:H" & lastRow).Copy Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1")
        End If

        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:=Array("US", "UK", "AUS"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        .AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=">10.00", Operator:=xlAnd
        ' And few more codes 
    End With
End Sub
```

---

I'm having second thoughts as to whether I actually **have** understood your question correctly.  If the code above **doesn't** make sense as an answer to your question, leave me a comment and I will delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You might specify `Criteria1` with an array returned by the following function.

```
Private Function FilterArray(Id As Integer, _
                             Clm As Long) As Variant

    Dim Fun() As Variant                  ' Function result
    Dim Choices As String
    Dim Sp() As String
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim i As Integer, n As Integer

    Select Case Id
        Case 0
            Choices = "JTKPV LLC,Living Inc.,Test item not to be found"
        Case 1
            Choices = "US,UK,AUS"
    End Select
    Sp = Split(Choices, ",")
    ReDim Fun(UBound(Sp))

    n = -1
    Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Columns(Clm)
    For i = 0 To UBound(Sp)
        If Not Rng.Find(Sp(i)) Is Nothing Then
            n = n + 1
            Fun(n) = Sp(i)
        End If
    Next i

    If n >= 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve Fun(n)
        FilterArray = Fun
    End If
End Function
```

This function is laid out for multiple use. It takes two arguments, the string sequence (0 for company names, 1 for countries) and a column number (1 for A, 9 for I) It will look for the item identified by `Id` in the column identified with `Clm`. If the item is found it will be added to the return array. If nothing is found the array will be returned blank (Empty).

Of course, you can put names into the `Choices` strings as you require, as many as you require, all comma separated (beware of unnecessary blanks). You can add more Choices, of course.

You can test this function with this testing procedure:-

```
Private Sub TestFilterArray()

    Dim Arr As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    Arr = FilterArray(0, 1)
    If Not IsEmpty(Arr) Then
        For i = 0 To UBound(Arr)
            Debug.Print i, Arr(i)
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

Observe the line `If Not IsEmpty(Arr)`. You need to incorporate it into your code also, because if `Arr` has no available choices you don't want the filter to be applied.

BTW, I specified the `Find` method in the minimum way. You may wish to extend the specification to make sure that previous manual searches do not interfere with the defaults my code uses. Read up on the `Find` method on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably look to see which is the last row and, if that is row 1, not perform the steps that you are trying to avoid:

```
Sub Test() 
    Dim lastRow As Long
    With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:H")
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("JTKPV LLC", "Living Inc."), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 
        If lastRow > 1 Then
            .Range("A1:H" & lastRow).Copy Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1")
        End If

        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:=Array("US", "UK", "AUS"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        .AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=">10.00", Operator:=xlAnd
        ' And few more codes 
    End With
End Sub
```