# How to use IF / Then Filter with Multiple Criteria Values

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I have a rather large Module that Creates a table, Finds data containing values in Column ‘C’, Sums the date together on a new/separate “Test” line, Filters to the original data, and then delete the original data.

This module is looping through several worksheets. Some of the worksheets does not have the ‘Find values.

If the search terms are not found, the formulas does return a zero.
However, when the `'Apply Filter: .Range("A3:M3").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Array("DREYER*", "EDY*"), Operator:=xlFilterValues`, is executed, there is nothing to filter.
So, then the `'Delete Rows: .Range("A4:M" & DataLastRow).EntireRow.Delete` ends up deleting ALL the data.

Then a `Run-time error '1004': Method 'ShowAllData' of object'_Worksheet' failed` populates.

So, I would like to perform an If / Then Filter.

Here is the beginning of my original syntax:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
    
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    With ws
        If .Index <> 1 Then
    
'Combine Dreyer's and Edy's Data & Delete Rows
   'Find the last used row in Column A
       Dim RngA As Long
       RngA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    
'Add Text in Column A, B, and C
    .Cells(RngA, "A").Value = "ICE CREAM"
    .Cells(RngA, "B").Value = "PINTS"
    .Cells(RngA, "C").Value = "TEST"
    
'Combine Data containing 'Dreyer's*' and 'Edy's*' data
  Dim RngTest As Range
     Set RngTest = .Range("C:C").Find("Test", LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
    
   RngTest.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "=sum(sumifs(D:D, C:C, {""DREYER'S*"" , ""EDY'S*""}))"
   RngTest.Offset(0, 2).Formula = "=sum(sumifs(E:E, C:C, {""DREYER'S*"" , ""EDY'S*""}))"
                .Cells(3).Formula = ws.Evaluate("=sum(sumifs(F:F, C:C, {""DREYER'S*"" , ""EDY'S*""}))")
                .Cells(5).Formula = ws.Evaluate("=sum(sumifs(H:H, C:C, {""DREYER'S*"" , ""EDY'S*""}))")
                .Cells(6).Formula = ws.Evaluate("=sum(sumifs(I:I, C:C, {""DREYER'S*"" , ""EDY'S*""}))")
        
   RngTest.EntireRow.Copy
      RngTest.EntireRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
'Filter "DREYER*" and "EDY*", and Delete Rows
   'Dim DataLastRow As Long
      DataLastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
'Apply Filter:
   .Range("A3:M3").AutoFilter.Filters (3), Criteria1:=Array("DREYER*", "EDY*"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    
'Delete Rows
        .Range("A4:M" & DataLastRow).EntireRow.Delete
         
'Clear Filter
   .ShowAllData
   .Cells.AutoFilter
        
'Replace Test for Dreyer's/Edy's
    RngTest.Replace "Test", "DREYER'S/EDY'S"
    
    'More code....
    
            End If
        End With
    Next ws
```

Looking through other strings, I was able to find:

```
If .AutoFilterMode = True And .FilterMode = True Then
   If .Range("$A$3:$M$807").Parent.AutoFilter.Filters(2).Criteria1 = "=4" Then
     '
     '~~> Rest of the code
     '
    End If
End If
```

[If-statement-autofilter-meets-criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32592101/if-statement-autofilter-meets-criteria)

[rondebruin](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win006_2.htm)

[how-to-add-if-condition-to-a-auot-filter-using-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43802160/how-to-add-if-condition-to-a-auto-filter-using-vba)

However, none of these seemed to address looking at multiple criteria.

I adjusted my original syntax to the following, but I’m pulling a Compile error: Expected: Then or GoTo

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
    
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
  With ws
     If .Index <> 1 Then
    
'Combine Dreyer's and Edy's Data & Delete Rows
   'Find the last used row in Column A
     Dim RngA As Long
       RngA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    
'Add Text in Column A, B, and C
   .Cells(RngA, "A").Value = "ICE CREAM"
   .Cells(RngA, "B").Value = "PINTS"
   .Cells(RngA, "C").Value = "TEST"
    
'Combine Data containing 'Dreyer's*' and 'Edy's*' data
   Dim RngTest As Range
      Set RngTest = .Range("C:C").Find("Test", LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
    
RngTest.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "=sum(sumifs(D:D, C:C, {""DREYER'S*"" , ""EDY'S*""}))"
RngTest.Offset(0, 2).Formula = "=sum(sumifs(E:E, C:C, {""DREYER'S*"" , ""EDY'S*""}))"
        
RngTest.EntireRow.Copy
    RngTest.EntireRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                
Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
'Filter "DREYER*" and "EDY*", and Delete Rows
    Dim DataLastRow As Long
    DataLastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
'Add AutoFilter
   .Range("A3:M3").AutoFilter.Filters
    
'IF/Then Filter
    ~-----Compile error: Expected: Then or GoTo-----~
    If .Range("A3:M3").AutoFilter.Filters(3).Criteria1 = "=Array("DREYER*", "EDY*")", Operator:=xlFilterValues Then
    
'Delete Rows
   .Range("A4:M" & DataLastRow).EntireRow.Delete
         
'Clear Filter
  .ShowAllData
   .Cells.AutoFilter
        
'Replace Test for Dreyer's/Edy's
   RngTest.Replace "Test", "DREYER'S/EDY'S"
    
    'More code....
    
            End If
        End With
    Next ws
```

1. Is there a way to use an If/Then filter for multiple criteria?
2. Should I change that portion to just a Find If/Then function, and then filter?

**Updated code based on @TimWilliams suggestions**

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim newRow As Range, rngVis As Range

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    With ws
        If .Index <> 1 Then
            
    'Combine Dreyer's and Edy's Data & Delete Rows
        Set newRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(1, 3) 'first row of summary
                newRow.Value = Array("ICE CREAM", "PINTS", "TEST")
                With newRow.Offset(0, 3)
                .Cells(1).Value = ws.Evaluate("=sum(sumifs(D:D, C:C, {""DREYER'S*"" , ""EDY'S*""}))")
                .Cells(2).Value = ws.Evaluate("=sum(sumifs(E:E, C:C, {""DREYER'S*"" , ""EDY'S*""}))")
                .Cells(3).Value = ws.Evaluate("=sum(sumifs(F:F, C:C, {""DREYER'S*"" , ""EDY'S*""}))")
                .Cells(5).Value = ws.Evaluate("=sum(sumifs(H:H, C:C, {""DREYER'S*"" , ""EDY'S*""}))")
                .Cells(6).Value = ws.Evaluate("=sum(sumifs(I:I, C:C, {""DREYER'S*"" , ""EDY'S*""}))")
                .Cells(7).Value = ws.Evaluate("=sum(sumifs(J:J, C:C, {""DREYER'S*"" , ""EDY'S*""}))")
                .Cells(8).Value = ws.Evaluate("=sum(sumifs(L:L, C:C, {""DREYER'S*"" , ""EDY'S*""}))")
                .Cells(10).Value = ws.Evaluate("=sum(sumifs(M:M, C:C, {""DREYER'S*"" , ""EDY'S*""}))")
                End With
                
            newRow.EntireRow.Copy
                newRow.EntireRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

                If .FilterMode Then .ShowAllData
                
                .Range("A3:M3").AutoFilter Field:=3, _
                   Criteria1:=Array("DREYER'S*", "EDY'S*"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
                
                With .AutoFilter.Range
                    On Error Resume Next 'find filtered rows (exclude header): ignore error if none
                    Set rngVis = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    If Not rngVis Is Nothing Then rngVis.EntireRow.Delete 'delete any rows if found
                End With
                
                .ShowAllData

    'Replace "Test" for "Dreyer's/Edy's"
        newRow.Replace "Test", "DREYER'S/EDY'S"

            End If 'index<>1
        End With   'ws
    Next ws
```

Before: [image: Before]

After: [image: After]
Everything should be in Row 76
The Formula for `.Cells(5)` went to row 77, Column E
The Formula for `.Cells(6)` went to row 77, Column F
The Formula for `.Cells(7)` went to row 78, Column D
The Formula for `.Cells(8)` went to row 78, Column E
The Formula for `.Cells(10)` went to row 79, Column E

Comment: It's not very clear from your description exactly what the problem is - if the search terms are not found then the inserted formulas will return zeros, and you can skip the filter/delete step.

Comment: @TimWilliams sorry about that! I updated the OP  This module is looping through several worksheets.  If the search terms are not found, yes the formulas return to zero.  
However, when the `'Apply Filter: .Range("A3:M3").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Array("DREYER*", "EDY*"), Operator:=xlFilterValues` , is executed, there is nothing to filter.  So, then the `'Delete Rows: .Range("A4:M" & DataLastRow).EntireRow.Delete` ends up deleting ALL the data.
Then `'Run-time error '1004': Method 'ShowAllData' of object'_Worksheet' failed' ` populates.

Comment: If `RngTest.Offset(0, 1).Value` is zero after running the SUMIF() then don't do the filter/delete

Comment: Would really help to have a before/after screenshot

Comment: @TimWilliams I updated the Before/After images

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED** - a few changes below

You could do something like this

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, newRow As Range, rngVis As Range
    
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws
            If .Index = 4 Then
                
                Set newRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).EntireRow 'summary row
                With newRow
                    .Cells(1).Value = "ICE CREAM"
                    .Cells(2).Value = "PINTS"
                    .Cells(4).Value = ws.Evaluate("=sum(sumifs(D:D, C:C, {""DREYER'S*"" , ""EDY'S*""}))")
                    .Cells(5).Value = ws.Evaluate("=sum(sumifs(E:E, C:C, {""DREYER'S*"" , ""EDY'S*""}))")
                    .Cells(6).Value = ws.Evaluate("=sum(sumifs(F:F, C:C, {""DREYER'S*"" , ""EDY'S*""}))")
                    .Cells(7).Value = ws.Evaluate("=sum(sumifs(h:h, C:C, {""DREYER'S*"" , ""EDY'S*""}))")
                    .Cells(8).Value = ws.Evaluate("=sum(sumifs(h:h, C:C, {""DREYER'S*"" , ""EDY'S*""}))")
                End With
                
                If .FilterMode Then .ShowAllData
                
                .Range("A3:M3").AutoFilter Field:=3, _
                   Criteria1:=Array("DREYER'S*", "EDY'S*"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
                
                With .AutoFilter.Range
                    On Error Resume Next 'find filtered rows (exclude header): ignore error if none
                    Set rngVis = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    If Not rngVis Is Nothing Then rngVis.EntireRow.Delete 'delete any rows if found
                End With
                
                .ShowAllData
                newRow.Cells(3).Value = "DREYER'S/EDY'S" 'fill this when done
                
            
            End If 'index<>1
        End With   'ws
    Next ws
                
End Sub
```

Comment: I updated my code in the bottom of the OP for your review.

Comment: Couple of updates on your code and questions:
`Dim NextA As Long` isn't in the acutal code.
"DREYER'S/EDY'S" will eventually replace "Test" in Column C, not go into Column D

Comment: I need the formulas to start in the newRow Column D. With newRow.Offset(1, 0) -> Changed to With newRow.Offset(0,3) In .Cells(1).Value -> this should be the first formula.

Comment: Why .Cells(2).Value and .Cells(3).Formula?

Comment: I also need to add more formulas in the `newRow`, cut it jumps rows on me when I enter `.Cells(5).Formula`.  I can't seem to find this method when Googling

Comment: (1) `Dim NextA As Long` was not cleaned up  (2) `newRow` is a range representing a row of 3cells, but you can change that to 5 if you need that `Set newRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(1, 5)`   (3)  `.Cells(3).Formula` should be ` .Cells(3).Value`